# How is lea useful for getting the address of the variable specially when you need to pass parameters to a procedure?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

**Getting the Address of a Variable**:

There is `lea` (Load Effective Address) instruction and the alternative
`OFFSET` operator. Both `OFFSET` and `lea` can be used to get the
offset address of a variable.
`lea` is more powerful because it also allows you to get the address
of an indexed variable. Getting its address can be
very useful in some situations, for example when you need to pass
parameters to a procedure. How?

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to use lea? Or are you asking about how to pass parameters to a procedure using it? I don't really understand your question.

Comment: how to pass parameters to a procedure using it?

Comment: That's two different things. `LEA` does not pass arguments, that depends on your calling convention. It just makes it easier to get the address of something that you can then pass on as usual. E.g. if your procedure expects the argument in the `bx` register you can do something like `lea bx, [array+si]`.

Comment: You don't need lea to do this. You can instead push the parameters to the stack and pull them in the procedure. With lea, you must leave some space in the procedure where you can store the parameters and then pass them.

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW: I think / hope that this is talking about using LEA in the *caller*.  You seem to be talking about passing data to a function via global variables ("leave some space"), but there's no reason to use LEA for that.  The function would just use `mov ax, [var1]` or something, not `mov bx, OFFSET var1` / `mov ax, [bx]`

Comment: `lea bx, [var1]` would be 4 bytes, vs. 3 for `mov bx, OFFSET var1`.  The only time it ever makes sense to use LEA with an addressing mode with no registers is in 64-bit mode, when you're actually using it with a RIP-relative addressing mode.  So if that's what you're asking, it's *not* useful, except with an address calculation that involves a register.  If you clarify the question, maybe with an example of what you're talking about, it could be answerable.